# clang tutorials segfaulting on "missing file"

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I've been trying to run a number of clang tutorials like [this one](http://swtv.kaist.ac.kr/courses/cs453-fall13/Clang%20tutorial%20v4.pdf) and I continuously get segfaults which I tracked with GDB:

```
Starting program: /analyser/a.out PrintFunctions.cpp
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
clang::Builtin::Context::InitializeTarget (this=0x6d1fe8, Target=...) at /opt/llvm/src/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Basic/Builtins.cpp:46
46      /opt/llvm/src/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Basic/Builtins.cpp: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  clang::Builtin::Context::InitializeTarget (this=0x6d1fe8, Target=...) at /opt/llvm/src/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Basic/Builtins.cpp:46
#1  0x00007fffedff47ba in clang::Preprocessor::Initialize (this=0x6d1d90, Target=...) at /opt/llvm/src/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Lex/Preprocessor.cpp:181
#2  0x00007ffff0efca72 in clang::CompilerInstance::createPreprocessor (this=0x7fffffffe5d8, TUKind=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/llvm/src/llvm/tools/clang/lib/Frontend/CompilerInstance.cpp:306
#3  0x0000000000402bcd in main (argc=2, argv=0x0) at PrintFunctions.cpp:86
(gdb) quit
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in the question.

Comment: If you're compiling with clang, you'll probably want to debug with [lldb](http://lldb.llvm.org/)

Comment: May I also suggest that you compile your local LLVM build with asserts enabled - it will catch all manner of things before you crash (and when you call the setup with wrong argument, rather than when you use it!)

Comment: @antiduh: Wouldn't matter - I use both, depending on exactly what I'm debugging, but gdb will debug clang and related tools just fine, and learning a new debugger isn't going to help in this case - it's most likely some bad configuration or similar.

Comment: Code in question: https://gist.github.com/marcinwyszynski/1ad6f3055614f372e260. Lines 72-76 are commented out to prevent this:

    /tmp/PrintFunctions-55ffb2.o: In function `main':
    /analyser/PrintFunctions.cpp:75: undefined reference to     `clang::TargetInfo::CreateTargetInfo(clang::DiagnosticsEngine&,     std::shared_ptr<clang::TargetOptions> const&)'
    clang-3.5: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)

Comment: Well, your commented out code is most likely critical... The code where you are crashing is exactly related to that. I use the latest (3.9) LLVM so probably not much help, but here's the setup of target in my compiler: https://github.com/Leporacanthicus/lacsap/blob/master/binary.cpp#L179

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Rebuild llvm & clang with:

```
 cmake ... -DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=1
```

or

```
 cmake ... -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

The latter will allow you to actually step into functions in clang and llvm, but the former will at least give you some fair warning when you skip over initialization or pass in bad parameters, etc, instead of crashing in some mysterious place when it's actually being used (which is typically much later than the assertion)

Step 2. Fix up the target info. This code has changed a few times over the past several years, so you will need to look up somewhere that does this. Looking at the code in for example `llvm/tools/llc/llc.cpp` is a good starting point. As this is different in just about every release, I'm not going to dig out the code from 2-3 years ago to figure out exactly what you need to do, but you do NEED to initialize SOME target, or your compilation will not succeed. Most likely you will get an assert in a suitable place if you enable assertions.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is complaining it can't find the source file containing `clang::Builtin::Context::InitializeTarget`, which is where your program crashes. While it could be that that code is broken, it is ***extremely*** unlikely. Ask the debugger for a traceback, that should give you an idea where the wrong arguments leading to the ultimate crash come from.

It does not segfault on "missing file".